# Android Webview - Back Button not working

Tags: android, button, webview, back

I have a webview where the back button is not functioning and causing nullpointer exceptions. I am using a single activity and checking the intent extras for the url to load. It all functions normal for opening links, just the back button does not go back to previous page in webview instead it crashes the activity.

**EDITTED:** updated code block to below suggestion. Still gives null pointer exception

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView; 
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebUrl extends Activity {

WebView myWebview; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if(extras != null) {
    String link = extras.getString("url");
    WebView myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webEngine);

    myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true) ; 
    myWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true) ; 
    myWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    myWebview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

    // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
    myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

               if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Load a page
            myWebview.loadUrl(link);
        }
        }
    }

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    if(myWebview.canGoBack() == true) {
        myWebview.goBack();
    } else {
        WebUrl.super.onBackPressed(); //Replace MyActivity With the name of your activity.
    }
 }
 }
```

Logcat Errors:

```
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at com.app.browser.WebUrl.onBackPressed(WebUrl.java:70)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2163)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2651)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2393)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1853)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:3683)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleImeFinishedEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3653)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2893)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5059)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
07-01 11:54:19.817: E/AndroidRuntime(10079):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Declare  `myWebview` as a class vairable

Answer (score 3):

`WebView myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webEngine);`

should be

`myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webEngine);`

You are declaring a new WebView in your if block, then trying to reference the class variable myWebView (which was never instantiated) in the onBackPressed(). You can also use this.myWebView in all cases if you want to be extra sure that you are always using the class variable.

Comment: also, you need to add some additional logic for the case when `extras == null`, i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but right now, it looks that if extras == null, the user will just see an empty webview.

Comment: Well that seems to have resolved it. just removing the Webview at the beginning. Between that and Davids suggestion it is now working properly.

Comment: please mark as answer if this was the solution that fixed your problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For starters your `onBackPressed` method is outside your class. That's why it's throwing a null pointer. I'm actually really suprised this even compiled and ran.

But you are way over complicating this, you do not need to replicate all of that code for two separate web pages. It looks like the settings you have for both Google and Mozilla are the same, in this case i would use this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebUrl extends Activity {

    WebView myWebview;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extras != null) {
            String link = extras.getString("url");
            WebView myWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webEngine);

            myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true) ; 
            myWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true) ; 
            myWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            myWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            myWebview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
            myWebview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

            // Load the URLs inside the WebView, not in the external web browser
            myWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

            if (savedInstanceState == null) {
                // Load a page
                myWebview.loadUrl(link);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if(myWebview.canGoBack() == true) {
                myWebview.goBack();
            } else {
                MyActivity.super.onBackPressed(); //Replace MyActivity With the name of your activity.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

From there, you can change specific settings based on what webpage users go to.

Comment: Ok. I used your suggestion. Was missing a closed bracket after mywebview.loadurl(link); I saved it, cleaned project and ran it and still gives same nullpointer as above.

Comment: What line is throwing the null pointer exception? You may need to use `MyActivity.super.onBackPressed()` instead of just `super.onBackPressed()` where MyActivity is the name of the current activity. Also, you may want to do some log printing to ensure that extras is in fact not null.

Comment: using your modified above, I changed MyActivity to WebUrl which is this Java class name, or should it be the MainActivity?

its giving error on line 41:

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. When you hit the back button did you actually have previous browsing history with this `WebView`? I think that despite your `if` statement, this code is still being run and you have no browsing history to go back to, thus null pointer. Try adding curly braces around your `if` and a `== true` in there. Although it's not necessary to do those last two things.

Comment: With or without browsing history it gives the nullpointer. Can you update your code block above to reflect the suggestion. Not sure where you are referring to

Comment: tried your updated block, same error with or without history on same line

Comment: So it throws an exception on the same line regardless of whether or not there is browsing history? If so something sounds fishy. I would ensure that all of your braces are in the correct spot otherwise you will keep getting the error.

Comment: updated code block above again, not seeing anything out of place, cleaned projects and no errors in eclipse. I am at a loss honestly hehe

Comment: above suggestion about removing the webview reference resolved it. thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

`myWebview` is not initialized properly.

`myWebView` is initializing when the following two conditions are true

```
 if(extras !=null)
```

and

```
 if(link.equals("http://www.google.com"))
```

So somehow any of these two condition is false. So the variable is not intialized. As a result it is null and throwing the exception